# Find the maximum value of the function $f(x,y)=\Big|\frac{3x-6y+2}{x-2y+1}\Big|$

Tags: functions

> Maximum value of the function in the region $|x|<\frac{1}{4}, |y|<\frac{1}{4}$
> $$f(x,y)=\Bigg|\frac{3x-6y+2}{x-2y+1}\Bigg|$$

I tried taking $x-2y=t$ then,
$|x-2y|<\frac{3}{4}$

So now, I have to maximize the following function in the region $|t|<\frac{3}{4}$

$$f(t)=\Bigg|\frac{3t+2}{t+1}\Bigg|$$

Checking the graph of the function, I got the maximum value $\frac{17}{7}$. But the answer given is $17$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably a typo or something, I get $\frac {17}7$ also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{17}{7}$ seems correct answer.

$ \displaystyle f(x,y)=\Bigg|\frac{3x-6y+2}{x-2y+1}\Bigg| = \Bigg|3 - \frac{1}{x-2y+1}\Bigg|$

As $\dfrac{1}{4} \leq x-2y+1 \leq \frac{7}{4}$, we have

$ \displaystyle -1 \leq 3 - \frac{1}{x-2y+1} \leq \dfrac{17}{7}$

We can see maximum of $f(x,y)$ is $\dfrac{17}{7}$.